# Invalid IAP product identifiers

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I understand that, for In-App Purchases, I make a request to the store, and then the app loads the UI, and the user taps "buy" and makes their purchase, and then the app delivers it.

This is a question about that first step: making the request.

For my game, I'm making an IAP to remove advertisements for $1.00.

My confusion lies in the product identifier. I can't use my Bundle ID in this scenario, because it contains hyphens. What do I put? Reverse domain? Any alphanumeric identifier?

I tried using something like `noads` in both iTunes Connect and my code, but this returns invalid.

Would I use `com.example.noads`?

Some other information related to my predicament:

- I'm testing on my iPhone 6. I am signed out of "iTunes and App Store." (screenshot below)
  [image: screenshot]
- I use the same thing between my code and iTunes Connect.
- I have a test account. I think I sign into that when I make the purchase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your sales contracts are in effect. It kept returning the identifiers as invalid until I set that up.

Comment: I didn't fill out Tax and Banking info yet. That may be it.

Comment: Turns out **this was my answer.** Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the product identifier you put a unique string across the whole Apple system. The idea is to put an identifier string rather than just an id like `1` or `53e31xp`.

In my particular case, I use reverse domain combined with a subset that describes the product, something like: `com.mydomain.myapp.mycategories.myproduct`

**Edit:** Note that after you have created an **IAP** you may have to wait a couple of hours for it to return as a valid product when making the request

Comment: Your edit may have been the remedy to my problem. Would I have to submit the IAP (with screenshot) and a build to Apple before it can be a valid product?

Comment: No. You create it and just wait for it to ... propague through the web(?)  but don't need to get it reviewed for it to be a valid product, so you can test it all you want on emulator and developer devices. It only needs to get reviewed for app store submition

Comment: Alright. Thank you! I'll try it and check your answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

So you mean you actually receive a SKProductsResponse with the invalidProductIdentifiers field containing the ID you've sent with the request?

If so, I would double check that you're **really** using the same string that you set in ITunes Connect.

If that checks out, the problem may lie with your test user. You **may only log in via the dialog** that iOS launches from your app, **don't sign in with the test user outside the app**, like in the app store app! If you have done so, your test user becomes useless, and you need to create a new test user.

Comment: I'm sure I'm using the same string. Yes, the only thing that comes back from the request is the only identifier I've sent as invalid. I might have to make a new test user or wait like @Christopher Francisco said.