# Cannot upload hosted content for In-App purchases to iTunesConnect

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, application-loader, iap-hosted-content, itmstransporter

I am trying to upload hosted content for in-app purchases, however I have been unable to succeed so far.

I have previously uploaded around 100 in-app purchases packages for my app using Application Loader. I used to be able to upload these packages before without any issues. Now I’ve noticed that the latest version of Application Loader (Version 3.0) doesn’t even give me the option to upload hosted content (see attached)?

[image]

So instead I’ve taken the time to use the iTMSTransporter bash script instead. However when I try to upload the content packs using:

iTMSTransporter -m upload

I am getting the following error:

Package Summary:

1 package(s) were not verified because they had problems:
    /Users/Cortana/Documents/iOS/Clients/AccentKit/InAppContent/854413379.itmsp - Error Messages:
        ERROR ITMS-90320: "The archive for In-App Purchase 'com.accentkit.AustraliaFemale1' is invalid. The 'IAPProductIdentifier' in the ContentInfo.plist must match the In-App Purchase Product ID."
[2018-04-14 07:12:45 MYT]  DBG-X: Returning 1

I’ve double checked and the value for IAPProductIdentifier on the ContentInfo.plist matches exactly with what’s setup on the In-App Purchase Product ID on iTunesConnect. (see attached screenshots) This error is making no sense to me.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: From my understanding this error can be caused by a bunch of different factors, and the error isn't really indicative of what those are. One thing that others have [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30922509/499581) is to "make sure that your sales contracts are in effect" (I'm not exactly sure what that means to be honest), but maybe worth a look nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you, there was an issue with Banking, however that's been fixed now and I am still encountering the same problem. :(

Comment: did my answer not help? :(

Comment: No, sorry, I am still having the issue.

Comment: I had a similar error, although I used the Organizer for the Upload. The reason in my case was that the InApp-Purchase was not "ready for sale" (checkbox at the top)

Answer (score 0):

If there was an issue with banking and your sales contract are according to you *theoretically* back in effect, they may not be *effectively* back in effect, that is, from Apple's servers point of view.

perhaps this is a process that takes up to a week and the only way to speed it up is to call their technical support.

this is where that'll happen : https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

I suspect it's likely that your app having been on monetary lockdown at any one point while the bank was an issue may have led into this buggy situation that apple may not have accounted for or that they have accounted for and want you to first go through their IT support process in order for them to first be able to asses that everything is in order.

cheers! :)